# `unittest.TestCase` makes global `warnings.filterwarnings` obsolete

Tags: python, warnings, python-unittest

I have a module with some methods that do raise an enormous number of warnings.
As it happens, the warnings are raised by an external module. In the given context they are not really useful but by their abundance quite annoying.

To suppress the warnings I intend to use the `warnings.filterwarnings` method. Because they are all over the place, I decided to suppress them once for all, i.e. on module level, and not again and again by the `catch_warnings` context manager.
Not very elegant but it does the trick.

Only - it doesn't do the trick in a `unittest.TestCase`, where this kind of suppression is simply ignored. I have figured out that some time between `TestCase` initialization and running the actual `test_method` a couple of filters are inserted in front of the filters list, among them `('default', None, <class 'Warning'>, None, 0)`, which then make the module-inserted filter at the rear useless.

Now the question is: how can I circumvent this "feature" and suppress the warnings in the test as well?

### MRE

do.py:

```py
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings(
    action='ignore',
    message='boring',
)


def main():
    warnings.warn('boring')
    warnings.warn('interesting')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`python do.py` only yields the "interesting" stuff.

test.py:

```py
from unittest import TestCase
import warnings

import do


class DoTest(TestCase):

    def test_do(self):
        with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as ws:
            do.main()
        self.assertTrue([ w for w in ws if 'interesting' in w.message.args ])
        self.assertFalse([ w for w in ws if 'boring' in w.message.args ])
```

`python -m unittest` test fails with this stack trace:

````bash
File "../test.py", line 13, in test_do
    self.assertFalse([ w for w in ws if 'boring' in w.message.args ])
AssertionError: [<warnings.WarningMessage object at 0x000001EE01A2D220>] is not false```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here is 2 examples:

```
from unittest import TestCase, mock
from unittest.mock import Mock

from do import main


# mock warnings for all class tests
class DoTest(TestCase):
    WARNING_MOCK = mock.patch('warnings.warn', return_value=Mock())

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
        cls.WARNING_MOCK.start()  # disable warnings before tests

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls) -> None:
        cls.WARNING_MOCK.stop()  # enable warnings after tests

    def test_do(self):
        main()


# or using 'with' statement to call a context manager
# in this case you'll mock warnings only for specific test
class DoTest2(TestCase):
    def test_do(self):
        with mock.patch('warnings.warn', return_value=Mock()):
            main()
```

Let's check `python -m unittest test`:

```
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.002s

OK
```

Comment: Thanks! Interesting approach, but this suppresses _all_ warnings and I actually need the interesting stuff during unittests (I've edited the original question in this respect).
Besides, I was hoping for a "once-for-all" solution and reluctant to edit all test files affected. (see my aproach in main ;).

Comment: @SchEma JFYI: you don't need to modify all tests. You can create 1 base test class and inherit from it. Or set `mock` somewhere before tests execution.

Comment: I've seen similar questions. Maybe I just don't understand. Look like people are trying to write tests for a `logging` or `warning` packages. Could you explain what problem you are solving?

Comment: Yes I could make my own derived `TestCase` class to inherit from, but I still need to update all my test modules. The problem I'm trying to solve is that the console output from my unittests is so huge that it must be further processed before it contains any human-readable useful information. And yes, of course, I'm testing the loggings and warnings of the application. Some of them are crucial.

Comment: I understand that some of them are crucial. I don't understand the problem. `logging.{SOMETHING}` will works. This is just fact. And this means that if you called it, it works. And this is not your `package` / `module`. Will you write tests for [filter](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.filter) or [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)? No. because it just doesn't make sense. But you can `mock` it and prepare data for tests.

Comment: @SchEma ok. Maybe I really don't understand something. But could you explain the nature of the logs? What are these logs for?

Comment: No worries, @Danila_Ganchar, it doesn't matter much. `unittest.TestCase` resets the `warnings.filters` to 'default' for a reason beyond me. In my case this leads to noisy output from the unittests. I was hoping for a _very_ easy way out, but I realize, it is going to be a little more complicated. I'll eventually have to deal with it on a test case or at least test module level. Well then, so be it. Nevertheless, many thanks for your input!